# Antimatter universe and Noether's theorem

Tags: symmetry, conservation-laws, antimatter, noethers-theorem, discrete

I am studying Feynman's *"symmetry in physical laws"*, where he talks about conservation laws for corresponding symmetries. (I know this is Noether's theorem, I am studying this from David Tong's lecture notes)

Now, if in a thought experiment I assume that our universe is made up of antielectrons, antiprotons, antineutrons and if I now perform an experiment, the experiment will run the same as if I perform it in a universe made up of electrons, protons, neutrons etc etc.
So there is a symmetry, so is there any kind of conservation law corresponding to this symmetry?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8518/2451

Comment: Note that Qmechanic's link is related because the matter-antimatter symmetry is not continuous as required by Noether's theorem.