# Conserved quantity corresponding to reflection symmetry

Tags: conservation-laws, symmetry, reflection, noethers-theorem, discrete

I know about [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem), but I don't actually know how to use it myself. Suppose our universe were symmetric with respect to reflections about planes. What conserved quantity would then exist by Noether's theorem?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8518/2451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Noether's theorem states that there exists a conservation law for every continuous (in fact, differentiable) symmetry. Reflection is a discrete symmetry, so the theorem is not applicable here.

But, in quantum mechanics, you have the parity operator $P$, that reflects the coordinates $$P\psi(\vec{r}) = \psi(-\vec{r})$$ Since $P^2 = I$, the operator $P$ has eigenvalues $\pm 1$. If the hamiltonian is invariant under reflection, i.e. $[H,P]=0$, every eigenfunction of the hamiltonian is also a eigenfunction of the parity operator with eigenvalue $p$ (called intrinsic parity). Then, the intrinsic parity is conserved.

Comment: If we had reflectional symmetry, then we would have $O(3)$ symmetry, which is a Lie group.

Comment: No, reflections are a discrete subgroup of $O(3)$, namely $O(3) = SO(3) \times \{I, -I\}$ is the direct product of the group of rotations (which is the Lie group) and the reflection group. In fact, is quite easy to find examples with reflection symmetry but not the whole $O(3)$ symmetry: a cube or an octahedron with the origin at their centers, for example.

Comment: I meant that our universe is already symmetric under $SO(3)$, so adding in rotational symmetry yields $O(3)$ symmetry.

Comment: Right, but the conserved quantities via Noether's theorem for $SO(3)$ and $O(3)$ are the same (angular moment). Adding the reflections doesn't add any new conserved quantity because they aren't a Lie group but a discrete group.

Comment: That seems weird to me...does the conserved quantity only depend on the connected component of the identity or something? Why do different Lie groups give rise to the same conserved quantity?

Comment: Yes, the derivation of Noether's theorem starts considering infinitesimal transformations $x \to x + \delta x$, which means that only the connected component of the identity really matters. See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem#Field-theoretic_derivation