# Conserved quantity associated with Permutation Symmetry?

Tags: conservation-laws, symmetry, noethers-theorem, discrete

Based on my crude understanding of Noether's Theorem, for each symmetry in physics, there is a conserved quantity associated with it. If so, what is the conserved quantity associated with permutation symmetry?

Comment: Permutation symmetry is discrete.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8518/2451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noether's theorem only gives conserved quantities for *continuous* symmetries, like rotation, not discrete rotations like permutations. See the question and answers here: [Conserved quantity corresponding to reflection symmetry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/190417/conserved-quantity-corresponding-to-reflection-symmetry?rq=1)