# Is there a conserved quantity for Parity Symmetry?

Tags: symmetry, noethers-theorem, discrete, parity

I've recently read about the Cobalt-60 experiment and Parity violation on weak interactions, what says the parity is not a symmetry on weak interactions.

But if I did not understand wrong EM and strong interactions parity isn't violated, so is it a symmetry? Could we apply the noether's theorem to reflections just like in rotations and translations? What would be the conserved quantity?
I'm new on this topics so corrections to some concept will be apreciated

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8518/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Noether's theorem only applies to continuous transformations.  Parity is discrete.

Comment: You are right, small detail that I did not take into account. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The conserved quantity is parity. Even states remain even, odd states remain odd. Discrete symmetries lead to discrete conserved quantities.