# What are the quantum numbers associated with inversion symmetry and time reversal symmetry?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, parity, time-reversal-symmetry

It is well known that for each symmetry in the system there must be a conserved quantum number, I would like to know what are the conserved quantum numbers associated with inversion and time-reversal symmetries. For example, in the continuum approximation AB-stacked bilayer graphene has the following Hamiltonian:

$H=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
  0 & v_{F}\pi^{+} & 0 & 0 \\
  v_{F}\pi^{-} &0 &  \gamma_{1} & 0\\
  0 &   \gamma_{1} & 0& v_{F}\pi^{+} \\
  0 & 0& v_{F}\pi^{-} &0 \\
\end{array}%
\right)$, with $\pi^{\pm}=p_{x}+ip_{y}$,  $p_{x,y}=-i\hbar \partial_{x,y}$, and $\gamma_1$ is the interlayer coupling (constant).
This Hamiltonian preserves both symmetries, so what are the associated quantum numbers?

Comment: *"It is well known that for each symmetry in the system there must be a conserved quantum number"* [citation needed] If you are referring to Noether's theorem, that only applies to *continuous symmetries*.

Comment: Noether's theorem works differently for discrete symmetries, but for these spacetime symmetries (e.g. parity, time-reversal), where the group is $\mathbb{Z}_2$, the charge is just $\pm 1$ (although it can be more complicated than this)

Comment: here's a relevant phys.SE question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8518/