# Why are there no conserved quantities with discrete symmetries?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, symmetry, noethers-theorem, discrete

After studying a bit of theoretical mechanics, I was a bit puzzled by why discrete symmetries do not allow for the existence of conserved quantities in general.

What would be a fundamental explanation of why this happens? More accurately, what impedes the existence of analogues to Noether's theorems for the discrete case?

Comment: A related question that might help out https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8518/23615